# extract different part from a string

Tags: string, bash

in linux bash i have a string like this:

```
 [57230.30555556, 57230.30902778, 57230.3125, 57230.31597222, 57230.31944444]
```

is it possible to extract for each index the part before the . and the part after between the . and the ,?
For example:

```
part1=57230
part2=30555556
```

Many thanks for the support

Comment: @fedorqui. Not really: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method.

```
cat file | awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {split($i, A,"\."); printf("part1=%s\npart2=%s\n", A[1], A[2]);}}'
```

file:
    57230.30555556, 57230.30902778, 57230.3125, 57230.31597222, 57230.31944444

output:
    part1=57230
    part2=30555556
    part1= 57230
    part2=30902778
    part1= 57230
    part2=3125
    part1= 57230
    part2=31597222
    part1= 57230
    part2=31944444